# Why aren't my changes showing?

Tags: magento2.2.4

I am trying to add some text to the page below-

```
/html/vendor/magento/module-customer-custom-attributes/view/frontend/templates//customer/form/register.phtml
```

I created a file at

```
/name/name/Magento_Customer_Custom_Attributes/templates/customer/form/register.phtml
```

I flushed all the caches multiple times but it still pulls the old file.

How can I get the correct template file to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes/templates/customer/form/register.phtml
```

If your `add/design/...` folder(s) is empty, then you can create them.

**Note**

How did I `Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes` get this?

If you have a look in `vendor/magento/module-customer-custom-attributes/Block/Form.php` then you will see `namespace` like this: `Magento\CustomerCustomAttributes\Block`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just needed to remove the _ between the customer custom attributes. Why is that? Is that true for everyone of these that has multiple words?

Comment: Yes, I believe that's the design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Module name which you are trying to override is incorrect.

It should be :

```
name/name/Magento_CustomerCustomAttributes/templates/customer/form/register.phtml
```

This is wrong:

```
name/name/Magento_Customer_Custom_Attributes/templates/customer/form/register.phtml
```

Change module name and then flush cache, it will fix the issue.